# Are there problems with my code that I am unaware of?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I started trying to learn python today with practically no prior experience in coding. I am using the website learnpython.org and following along and doing their exercises.

On the loop exercise, it asks me to loop through and print out all even numbers from the numbers list in the same order they are received, and to not print out any numbers that come after 237 in the sequence.

My solution to the problem seems to have worked, but their solution is much different. Is there anything wrong that may affect something I am unaware of with my code?

```
numbers = [
    951, 402, 984, 651, 360, 69, 408, 319, 601, 485, 980, 507, 725, 547, 544,
    615, 83, 165, 141, 501, 263, 617, 865, 575, 219, 390, 984, 592, 236, 105, 942, 941,
    386, 462, 47, 418, 907, 344, 236, 375, 823, 566, 597, 978, 328, 615, 953, 345,
    399, 162, 758, 219, 918, 237, 412, 566, 826, 248, 866, 950, 626, 949, 687, 217,
    815, 67, 104, 58, 512, 24, 892, 894, 767, 553, 81, 379, 843, 831, 445, 742, 717,
    958, 609, 842, 451, 688, 753, 854, 685, 93, 857, 440, 380, 126, 721, 328, 753, 470,
    743, 527
]
#My solution
for i in numbers:
    if i == 237: 
        break
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(i)
        continue
#Their solution
for number in numbers:
    if number == 237:
        break
    if number % 2 == 1:
        continue
    print(number)
```

Something else I noticed is that the way we checked for even numbers is different. I used this: `if i % 2 == 0` and they used this: `if number % 2 == 1`. Why do they both seem to do the same thing?

Comment: Their solution is checking if a number is odd, if so go to the next item (continue), otherwise if it's even print the number. I'd say your solution is better as it expresses the requirements more explicitly.

Comment: Okay, cool, thanks a ton!

Comment: No problem. Also you don't need the `continue` statement after `print(i)`